# How to understand the fact real number is the equivalent class of basic sequences

Tags: real-analysis

How to understand the fact real number is the equivalent class of basic sequences？
Why the sequences only differ from each other with one zero sequences.

I only know one equivalence is a sequences with constant sequence $=$ rational number, and

a sequence without constant sequence $=$ irrational number. ${3,3.14,3.141...}= \pi$

“all basic sequences only differ from each other with one zero sequences” means that all basic sequences which converges to one real number are the same, and not Pi's sequences and E's sequences.

i.e. Here the "all basic sequences" are not all sequences of all real numbers but only all sequences of one real numbers. Is my interpretation right?

Comment: Consider the class of rational sequences that converge to $x$. We want to identify $x$ with that class of rational sequences. But that would be a silly definition, it would define $x$ in terms of $x$. And we can't even say converges, because we would have to mention $x$. So we get sneaky, and talk about **Cauchy** sequences of rationals. And there are many sequences of rationals that informally have the same limit. But any two differ from each other by a null sequence (one that approaches $0$). That combination of tricks will do it.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Hi, “all basic sequences only differ from each other with one zero sequences” means that all basic sequences which converges to one real number are the same, and not Pi's sequences and E's sequences. Is my interpretation right?

Comment: Yes, as a simple example, the sequence $3,3.1,3.141,\dots$ (you can imagine the rest) would be in the same equivalence class as $99, 3,1. 3.1415,\dots$. So would the sequence obtained from the string of better and better decimal approximations of $\pi$ by adding $(-1)^n/n^2$ to the $n$-the term of the sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not too clear from your question what concepts you understand well, and what might be bugging you, so I'll just through out some buzzwords in italics.

When you take that sequence you mentioned that corresponds to $\pi$, we see that the numbers $3,3.1,3.14,\ldots$ seem to be approaching some limit. Even though each term in the sequence is rational, the limit is not a rational number. So this means the rationals are not *complete* as a metric space.

The precise definition of complete metric space is that every *Cauchy sequence* converges to a limit in the metric space.

The real numbers are the *completion* of the rational numbers, where the completion is a process where we take a metric space that is not necessarily complete and then add a bunch of new elements that correspond to limits of Cauchy sequences so that it is complete. (There are many ways to do this, but the precise definition of a completion involves a *Universal Mapping Property*, which informally means in this case that you don't add more than you need to.)

Now, there are other constructions of the completion of $\mathbb{Q}$, but the one you are mentioning is where you add the new "limits" by just letting each element be a Cauchy sequence (this also works for arbitrary metric spaces, which is nice). Then, you can sort of see that you have at least one element that corresponds to each Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Then, you can try to define a metric on these Cauchy sequences by letting the distance between $\{a_{n}\}$ and $\{b_{n}\}$ to be $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{|a_{n}-b_{n}|}$. The distance is well-defined because $\{a_{n}\}$ and $\{b_{n}\}$ are Cauchy sequences. However, it might be possible that two different sequences $\{a_{n}\}$ and $\{b_{n}\}$ are "distance zero" from each other.

This is the "zero sequences" you mentioned. We tried to complete the space by adding limits, but we added too many, and many many sequences correspond to the same real number, so we have to let our space instead by the Cauchy sequences with the *equivalence condition* that pairs of sequences that differ by a zero sequence are considered the same.

Finally, you need to show that our metric space is complete. By this, I mean if $\{a_{ni}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ are a countably number of Cauchy sequences that converge in our new metric space, then it converges to a limit in our new metric space. One can show that $\{a_{nn}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ works, so the key idea here is diagonalization.

Comment: One can define the completion of a metric space without any reference to a universal mapping property, and simply derive that property as a theorem.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I automatically assumed that one should start first from the abstract property and then construct it, rather than the other way around. I guess this is just because constructions are harder to remember than the properties for me.

Comment: Interesting: I’m largely the other way. I tend to find constructions quite natural and universal properties somehow rather artificial.